# vim syntax off when one buffer quit?

Tags: vim

I have two buffers in my vim session, and I set syntax on in my vimrc , I used minibufexpl to manage bufs.

I used **:q** to quit the current buf, but the other buf would auto set the syntax off, I have to use :set syntax=on to open the syntax highlight manually. Could someone give me a solution  that not set the syntax off automatic after one buf quit? Thanks!! (I tried **:bd** to quit the buf instead of **:q**, sometimes it stay the syntax on but sometimes no).

Comment: `:set syntax=on` will force highlighting of current buffer using `syntax/on.vim` script, it won’t enable syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using minibufexpl.vim, add the following to your .vimrc:

```
let g:miniBufExplForceSyntaxEnable = 1
```

It appears to be caused by a bug in vim. For the details, refer to the [release notes for minibufexpl version 6.3.1](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159)

Note that this will work for **:bd** but not **:q**

Comment: This not working in v 6.5.2 (released on June 17, 2013)

Answer (score 2):

This might be much too late, but I was experiencing the exact same problem and found that adding the line

```
set hidden
```

to my .vimrc solves this problem. This makes vim hide buffers rather than closing them when you enter ":q" It also seems to keep my syntax highlighting enabled between files when I navigate with minibufexplorer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use syntax enable or syntax on in your vimrc. For more info use :h syntax.

Ok then check that your syntax files are correct, it should looke like this

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set syntax=cpp11 <-- it's the line I have for cpp files.

Hope this help.

Comment: I already set syntax on in my vimrc. And the point is when i quit the  one file, other files would automatic set syntax off.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should add this line to `gvimrc`:

```
autocmd BufDelete * syntax on
```

Comment: Tested in v 6.5.2 (released on June 17, 2013)

Answer (score 0):

A plugin is misbehaving.

After closing the buffer (and losing syntax highlighting), investigate, by e.g.

```
:verbose set syntax?
```

This will show something like

```
 syntax=cpp
  Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\syntax\syntax.vim
```

You might also be able to see what goes wrong my doing

```
:debug quit
```

If all else fails, try eliminating sources of errors by disabling plugins one-by-one (or removing all, and enabling one-by-one). At some point the problem will appear/disappear and you have found the guilty party.